# In Slim v3 how to access $container properties in routes?

Tags: php, slim

My Setup is like this:

I request my settings from this file and store them in the settings variable.

```
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/settings.php';
```

Next create a new Slim instance like so:

```
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['logger'] = function($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new \Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $file_handler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path']);
    $logger->pushHandler($file_handler);
    return $logger;
};
```

Then i am calling my route:

```
$this->get('/testlogger, __testReq::class . ':test);
```

The above route calls the "test" method inside of my class. Which gets loaded over autoload. Below my class (controller) in which i am trying to access the container like explained on Slim Website.

```
class __testReq {
   function test($request, $response){
       //According to Documentation i am supposed to be able to call logger like so:
       $this->logger->addInfo("YEY! I am logging...");

    }
}
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html) (Documentation uses HomeController class as example):

> Slim first looks for an entry of HomeController in the container, if it’s found it will use that instance otherwise it will call it’s constructor with the container as the first argument.

So in your `class __testReq` constructor, you need to set up the object:

```
class __testReq {

    // logger instance
    protected $logger;

    // Use container to set up our newly created instance of __testReq
    function __construct($container) {
        $this->logger= $container->get('logger');
    }

    function test($request, $response){
        // Now we can use $this->logger that we set up in constructor
        $this->logger->addInfo("YEY! I am logging...");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it actually worked. I still would like to know if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Better how? You can create a factory in your container that returns an instance of the controller, which you can set up in that factory. I'll update my answer.

Comment: i mean without have to manually repeat the same code inside the constructor of every class... Am not sure!?

Comment: What I personally do for common required dependencies like `logger` or `view`, is to create a `BaseController` and in constructor of that class I set up common dependencies, then I extend every other controller from that BaseController class. If required, I'll override `__construct($container)` method, so setting up common dependencies is easy as calling `parent::__construct($container);` and I can do class specific set up as well. I think this would be another question, adding it to the answer here does not make much sense.